# Show DataGrid columns in ContextMenu

Tags: wpf

I have a datagrid and I will show ContextMenu.
This ContextMenu should contain columns of the grid.
This is my code, but it does not work.
Please help me...!

```
    <Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="mainGrid" >
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu  
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataGridColumns}">
                <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Caption}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>


    public IList<DataGridColumn> DataGridColumns
    {
        get
        {
            return  this._columns;
        }
        set { }           
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "[...] but it does not work"? Please clarify that.

Comment: I can not see the Menuitems. It is empty

Comment: And _columns is not empty...?

Comment: private IList<DataGridColumn> _columns;
private void ColumnsSettings()
      {       _columns.Clear();
                foreach (DataGridColumn column in mainGrid.Columns)
                {
                    DataGridColumn setting;
                    DataGridColumn dgColumn = column;
                        setting = new DataGridColumn {
                            Caption = dgColumn.Header.ToString()
                        };
                    _columns.Add(setting);
                }}

Comment: No, _columns and DataGridColumns are not Empty

Comment: You probably need to work with `ContextMenu.PlacementTarget` to get the `DataContext`

Comment: Where is the DataGridColumns property defined? And what is the DataContext of the DataGrid?